# combine template with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I'm trying to make a service that will take a template and a controller, combine the two, and then send them to the frontend framework for injection to the DOM. The service would allow me to inject a modal at any time in the application.

The actual injection of the modal is already handled by uikit (bootstrap like framework). so the problem is only how to bind a controller/scope to a view-partial template. It would look something like this:

```
angular.module('user', ['modal'])
.controller('userCtrl', userCtrl)
.controller('userModalCtrl', userModalCtrl);

function userCtrl(modal){
  var uc = this;
  var modalConf = {
    templateUrl: 'components/user/tmpl/profilemodal.tpl.html',
    controller: 'userModalCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'um'
  }
  uc.openModal = modal.confirm(modalConf);
}

function userModalCtrl(){
  var um = this;
  um.user = {
    name: 'John doe',
    email: 'john.doe@example.com'
  }
}
```

Usually I would use a directive, but in this case, I don't want to add any markup to the application view beforehand. If I could call a directive programmatically, perhaps that would solve the issue.

I have been able to call the template, and have it injected in the DOM, correctly .. the question is... how do I bind a controller to it?

```
angular.module('modal', [])
.factory('modal', modalSrv);

function modalSrv($templateRequest, ukModal){
  var service = {};
  service.confirm = function (content, callback) {
    $templateRequest(content).then(function(data){
      new ukModal.confirm(data, callback);
    });
  };
  return service;
}
```

This service will correctly collect the HTML template referenced in `content`, and then send it to ukModal (.confirm specifies a type of modal), that in turn injects it in the DOM. the question is .. how do I bind a controller/scope to this template, before sending it off to ukModal?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense so far. What higher level problem are you trying to solve? How did you plan to insert this, and from where? Are you talking about inserting within scope of existing controller already active in view? Objective is not very clear

Comment: Updated question with use-case to clarify.

Comment: Seems to me a simple `modalOpen` service would help you. Then in that service before  calling `modal.confirm(modalConf);` you modify the config based on params passed to whatever service method you create. I have one app with about 50 different modals and I use one service method to open them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do directive's job, even if there would be other Angular-compliant ways to do that.

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'components/user/tmpl/profilemodal.tpl.html',
    controller: 'userModalCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'um'
  };
});
```

and

```
var modalElement = $compile('<modal>')($scope);
var modal = new ukModal.confirm(modalElement , callback);
```

The most obvious problem here is that `$scope` should be actual parent's scope. If it is not, make sure that the directive doesn't depend on it in any way, you can even pass empty object instead of `$scope`.

The less obvious problem is memory leaks. Watch for them. Non-ng code in conjunction with detached nodes is leakage-prone.